# Text not added to mms intent with image

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am creating an intent that will send some text and image to the messaging app. But when messaging app is opened, it only shows the image and no text with it. Can anybody help? Below is my code.

```
String pathofBmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), Global.bitmap, "DriverImage", null);
Uri bmpUri = Uri.parse(pathofBmp);

Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
smsIntent.setType("*/*");
smsIntent.setPackage("com.android.mms");
smsIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, messageBody);
smsIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
smsIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(smsIntent);
```

Comment: There is no requirement for an `ACTION_SEND` activity to support both `EXTRA_TEXT` and `EXTRA_STREAM` on the same `Intent`, only one. Also note that not every device has `com.android.mms`, and that not every user wants to use `com.android.mms`.

Comment: So what should I do? Is there any workaround to send both image and text?